# I don't seem to be entering text at a password prompt in the terminal

Tags: command-line

I have been unable to type my password in the Ubuntu terminal. Noticed that it was requesting a Unix password. Where did that come from?? I did login to the Unity desktop using my Ubuntu password but changed nothing that I know of.

Being unable to type in the terminal is not new. Any sudo apt-get is followed by a password request. I am unable to type at that point. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Any command leading with *sudo* will ask for a password, unless you provided it permanently before. Your Linux password is your UNIX password, and vice versa. Please advise if you can type in the window of a GUI program, such as a web browser, or the text editor app from the programs list. Also please advise which number version of Ubuntu you use. Please click [edit] to answer and put the answers in the body of the question so all may see; please do NOT reply as a Comment.

Comment: If you have an administrator's account, if you try to execute some elevated command using sudo, it will ask for your administrator's password, to prove that you're authorized to run that elevated command. For security reasons, when you type your password, the characters are not displayed... so somebody can't look over your shoulder and see your password.

Answer (score 4):

Your issue requires a two part answer:

Linux can be described as a "Unix-like" operating system. It's not Unix, but functions very similarly to it, to the point where many people would call it a clone. Many utilities were directly moved/cloned from Unix operating systems to Linux; awk, sed, etc. Hence why it asks for a "unix" password.

As for being unable to type, Linux/Unix do not display the length of your password in the command line, and accomplish this by showing absolutely nothing when you're typing it. You **ARE** still typing, it's just not showing anything in case someone's looking over your shoulder. Enter your full password and press enter, and it will still get sent through. You can even use backspace to clear the password field, you just can't see what you're doing when you do it. Installing/uninstalling programs with apt is a root-level feature, so it asks for your administrator password, which by default is the same that you log in with.